# How to reset id and data-attr while or faster clone a element

Tags: jquery, html

I want to clone this div:

```
<div id="parentdiv">
  <div id="child1" data-whatelse="123">Child Text</div>
  <div id="child2" data-whatelse="123">Child Text
  <div id="chilfofchild" data-whatelse="123">Child of Child Text</div>
</div>
```

So I clone it and reset the id to a new one.

```
$('#parentdiv')
.clone()
.attr('id', my_new_id_for_cloned_div ).
insertAfter('#parentdiv');
```

How I can reset all id and data-attributes which are inside the cloned div?

Comment: iterate over the cloned element and find each element that needs ID and data attribute and set as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to do this myself. Use a function to send the cloned object and the new ID through and return the updated clone object.

```
//your parent function
var parentClone = $('#parentdiv').clone(true, true);

updateId(parentClone, your-new-id)
parentClone.insertAfter('#parentDiv');

//function to update the IDs
function updateId(theClone, newId) {
        $(theClone).find("[id]").add(theClone).each(function() {
            this.id = this.id.replace('key-to-update', newId);
        })
    }
```

I'm trying to make the last line of the function clear enough for anyone to understand:  basically it reads "set the id of the clone to the current id, but replace *something* (key-to-update) in this string with the new id.  I used an "x" (my cloned object is hidden; if yours is viewable and is called "parentDiv" maybe you could replace "Div" with a number or timestamp (I replaced my "x" with a timestamp.)

Comment: and how i cann update the data-attr in the same step, or should i use this function twice?

Comment: You're already accessing each element of  "Parent".  If you even gave each "child-x" the same class as parent's id, it'd be trivial to update the child data attributes: 

`$('.child-parentDiv').data('whatelse', newValue)`

Answer (score 2):

Loop through all the divs and append the new clone ID. If you just need to clear the value of the data attr, then uncomment the 1st line. 
To remove the data attribute itself, leave it as it is.

```js
var
  outputContainer = $('.output-container'),
  originalDiv = $('#parentdiv'),
  cloneParent = originalDiv.clone();

CloneIt('-clone-1')

function CloneIt(cloneID) {
  $.each(cloneParent.find('*'), function(ind, elem) {
    $(elem)
    .attr('id', $(elem).attr('id') + cloneID)
    //.attr('data-whatelse', '') // clears the value
    .removeAttr('data-whatelse') // removes the attribute itself!
  });

  cloneParent.attr('id', cloneParent.attr('id') + cloneID);  
  outputContainer.append(cloneParent)
}
```

```css
.output-container {
background: #efefef;
}
#parentdiv {
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="output-container">
  <div id="parentdiv">
    <div id="child1" data-whatelse="123">Child Text</div>
    <div id="child2" data-whatelse="123">Child Text
      <div id="chilfofchild" data-whatelse="123">Child of Child Text</div>
      <p id="chilfofchild" data-whatelse="123">Child of Child Text -- P element</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: great, but for me it possible that the cloneed element is not only a div, it can be every kind of element - how i should use your code in this case?

Comment: Changed the div to * inside CloneIt(). Have updated the code as well